# Does proton make neutron charged by the process of induction/friction/conduction?

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics

If two bodies undergo friction, the one of the bodies which has electrons less tightly bound than the other loses them. Here the protons do also have charged quarks which they could exchange with neutrons to make them charged either by the process of conduction (may not be possible by friction), but it does not happen I think so. If so, Why?

Edit: Can the neutron develop induced charge due to protons inside the nucleus? Though we can't expect exchangeable isolated quarks, can we expect them to orient or get settled to one side, so that neutron can develop induced charge?

I might have misunderstood sometimes, if so, pardon me and explain.

Comment: You are thinking of elementary particles like solid balls in classical mechanics. And that's a no no :D Plus there are lots of conservation laws that must hold, especially if you are looking at charge...

Answer (score 1):

In your profile you do not give any details, for example your age. This question shows somebody who has little contact with physics, so here goes an answer assuming this.

> If two bodies undergo friction, the one of the bodies which has electrons less tightly bound than the other loses them.

Electrons are bound to atoms by the electromagnetic interaction, which is relatively weak.

> Here the protons do also have charged quarks which they could exchange with neutrons to make them charged either by the process of conduction or friction,

Quarks though they also have electric charge, are bound in the atoms by the [strong force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_force), which is more than a hundred times stronger than the electromagnetic. Actual quarks can never be free because the larger the distance from the center of the proton the stronger the binding force.

> but it does not happen. Why?

The analogy does not hold because of the strong force.

After edit:

The neutron has no measurable  [electric dipole moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment). The current limit is less than 2.9×10^−26e·cm .  It is still within the predictions of the standard model. If a larger dipole moment existed it would be% [CP violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_violation) coming from strong interactions.

Within a nucleus it is not possible to isolate a neutron and see whether it is whole and has a separate distribution. Nuclei do have [electric quadrupole moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_quadrupole_resonance) and possibly if one [could solve for a nucleus](http://www.int.washington.edu/talks/WorkShops/int_09_1/People/Savage_M/Savage.pdf) one might find that neutrons when whole within the nucleus are temporarily skewed by the internal interactions; it is a many body problem and not of particular interest overall.

---

% Read the introduction in [this paper](http://www.bnl.gov/edm/review/files/references/pospelov.annphys.318.2005.119.pdf) for why an electric dipole moment is CP violating

Comment: I agree anna that electrons are bound by electromagnetic interaction which is relatively weaker than the strong force between between those of quarks.If you consider proton and neutron both contain quarks which are bound in them by same strong force.Relatively the force may be stronger than electromagnetic interaction between those of electrons but between those of same quarks it would not relatively mean stronger force.So the strong force of binding could not be the reason for neutrons not getting charged

Comment: read up the link. The quarks cannot get out of the triplet that makes up each hadron because of color confinement " Unlike all other forces (electromagnetic, weak, and gravitational), the strong force does not diminish in strength with increasing distance. After a limiting distance (about the size of a hadron) has been reached, it remains at a strength of about 10,000 newtons, no matter how much farther the distance between the quarks.[4] In QCD this phenomenon is called color confinement;

Comment: I agree anna that free quarks are not observed and even they are formed by colliding accelerated protons at high speed.If free quarks cannot come out of hardons quark-antiquark pair can come out of it,as according to you gluon tube elongates until it reaches where it snaps to form another quark-antiquark pair.Now you may argue that high energy is required even to get that pair out.But after all another quark-antiquark composition of the same strength is pulling it out.So color confinement may not be the correct explanation for nuetrons not getting charged by protons.

Comment: There exist in scattering charge exchanges , http://prc.aps.org/abstract/PRC/v50/i6/p2742_1 .Rubbing does not exist as a concept ; when the energy of the neutron proton interaction is low there is capture of the neutron and a deuteron is formed. Within a nucleus with protons and neutrons the state function is stable and any exchanges do not change the composition of the nucleus except mathematically as a description of possible diagrams.

Comment: I accept your thought that there exists exchanges between proton and neutron through mesons or pions.Further you suggested that composition of the subatomic particles does not change even after that,so if you can define why composition of protons and neutrons does not change,it might take us to answer of the query.

Comment: Question has been edited.